# vscode not select correct dart sdk

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have download different dart sdk and wish to switch sdk for different flutter project. In vscode I have add two downloaded dart sdk path into settings, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to change dart sdk location path, I selected `Dart SDK 2.7.0` but vscode keep pointing back to the old dart sdk location (image below with `Current setting`)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution, inside root project folder create `.vscode` folder if don't have.

Next create `settings.json` if don't have. Paste the json below to overwrite current project sdk path. **Remember to replace to your own sdk path**

```
{
   "dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\\flutter_1.22.6",
   "dart.sdkPath": "C:\\dart\\dart-sdk_2.7.0"
}
```

No need to change sdk path by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> each time.

**Tip here, if facing any pub cache issue while building, just `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` again**

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, and create a launch.json, by going to Run in VScode menu, then Add Configurations,

Add the following, mind you, your project's directories.

```
    {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "name": "YOUR APP NAME",
            "cwd": "/home/u/Projects/fireflutter/live-projects/YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "flutterMode": "debug",
            "args": [
                // "--web-port",
                // "8080",
                // "--no-sound-null-safety",
                // pass your arguments here, whatever you would type 
                //in the terminal when you would use i.e 
                //flutter run --no-sound-null-safety[I love null safety by the way, 
                //but this is a common problem for people who still want to opt out of it.
            ],
        }
    ],
    "dart.flutterSdkPath": "/home/u/Downloads/sdks/flutter",
    "dart.sdkPath": "/home/u/Downloads/sdks/flutter/bin/dart",
}
```

Comment: Leaving your SDK in Downloads and linking to that location should be avoided.